# Как записать переменную с js в текстовый файл?

Tags: javascript

```
    <script>
    var text = "text";
    </script>
```

Нужно переменную text записать в text.txt

Comment: Используйте `download` атрибут.

Answer (score 3):

Если файл нужно записать на компьютере, есть вариант записать в папку для загрузок, указанную в настройках браузера:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick = function() {
   var text = "text";
    var csvData = 'data:application/txt;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text);
    this.href = csvData;
    this.target = '_blank';
    this.download = 'txt.txt';
}
```

```html
<a href=#>записать</a>
```

Просто кликните ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить файл на клиенской стороне - никак. На сервере можно например через node:

```
fs=require("fs")
fs.writeFileSync("txt.txt", "my text",  "ascii")
```

По поводу тега `download`: Он не позволяет сохранять файл. Но может сформировать его и дать пользоателю на закачку при нажатии на кнопку/ссылку. 
Вот пример:

```
<script> var text = 'как записать строку в файл ".txt" с помощью js?'; document.write( '<a href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURIComponent(text) + '" download="text.txt">text.txt</a>' ) </script>
```

Comment: К сожалению, в этом ответе не показаны некоторые возможности сохранить файл действуя только на client-side. Было бы здорово если бы ты написал более развёрнутый ответ опираясь, например, на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file). Минус не мой :)